# What is the difference between a curiosity and having a sexual desire?

Tags: grammaticality, british-english, vocabulary, dictionaries

What is the difference between a curiosity and having a sexual desire? Can they be used interchangeably?

From what I understand, "Sexual Desires" are what you get when you "know" what that something is that you like already. Curiosity is the desire of "wanting" to know what you "LIKE" so for example:

So if I use the word "curious" or "curiosity" instead of sexual desire to refer to having a sexual state of mind, am I wrong or they the same thing? Does curiosity also motivates and warrants the action whereas sexual desires are something you think about and never act on?

Comment: Maybe you've been overly influenced by movies such as [I Am Curious (Yellow)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Am_Curious_(Yellow)). Not everything is about sex, including curiosity.

Comment: Curiosity is not by itself erotic, but you can compare being sexually curious about a desire to having that desire.

Comment: ...I tried without success to find any instances in Google Books of ***[a] curious familiar*** referencing something like a witch's unusual (Manx?) cat. Ideally including an allusion to the ***cat's*** curiosity (which after all they are well-known for having, even if it kills them! :) But if I ***had*** found one, I certainly wouldn't have expected sexual overtones as well!

Comment: The first thing I thought of relating "curious" to sexuality was "bi-curious" (willing to experiment with that sexuality without identifying as that sexuality).

Comment: They are not the same thing at all. Having a sexual desire is having a sexual desire. When the mind is in a state of strong desire, a person is said to be *aroused* (*sexually aroused*), or--colloquially--*horny* or *randy* (in Commonwealth English). Being curious is a state of wanting to know more. Though sex and sexuality can be a topic of curiosity, sex and sexuality are not associated with being curious especially, compared to other topics.

Comment: You have already demonstrated non-sexual curiosity by posting this question. You were curious about the difference between the words so you posted the question to satisfy that curiosity. Did you mean to ask about the difference between having a sexual desire and being _sexuallly_ curious?